# Configure Apache camel route from using URL path wildcards and configure to using the from URL path

Tags: spring-mvc, apache-camel

Configure Apache camel route from using URL path wildcards and configure to using the from URL path.

Such that any request to `[from_host][port]/path/*****/api/****` will be forwarded to `[to_host][port]/path/{{*****/api/****}}`

Comment: Check out the Camel documentation on [http proxying](http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-camel-as-a-http-proxy-between-a-client-and-server.html).

Comment: Thanks @Ralf the documention was very useful